# how to delete data from a table?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm a laravel programmer and I have to develop a project for college in spring.
I am not able to delete data from the table.
In laravel, to delete data from the table, you have to create a form and inside this form you can pass the delete method.
I've done a lot of research but the examples don't show the html.

Controller:

```
// Delete
@DeleteMapping("/autor/deletar/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") long id)
{
    authorservice.delete(id);
}
```

AuthorServiceImplement

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    repositorio.delete(repositorio.findById(id).get());
}
```

Html

```
<a th:href="@{/autor/deletar/{id}(id=${author.id})}">
    Deletar
</a>
```

When I try to delete, I get an error "get method not supported". Do I have to change anything in html anyway or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing it via a web browser, it's always using the HTTP Method GET. You need to use Postman or Insomnia for exemple to send HTTP requests.
As you are using `@DeleteMapping("/autor/deletar/{id}")` it says that this function is called when doing an HTTP request to `/autor/deletar/{id}` with the method `DELETE`

**EDIT**

If you just want to test it via your web browser, you can always replace `@DeleteMapping("/autor/deletar/{id}")` by `@GetMapping("/autor/deletar/{id}")`

Comment: Is it the only alternative?

Comment: @gobsruiz01 if you want to correctly use the HTTP protocol, yes. But, if you just want to test it via your browser just replace your @DeleteMapping("/autor/deletar/{id}") with @GetMapping("/autor/deletar/{id}")